# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined error using with ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource, sqldatasource

Yes, i know. Possible dublicate question.

But it's different situation on gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid_Goster" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            Height="144px" Width="316px">

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [AVUKAT]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And i get error like this:

> Both DataSource and DataSourceID are
>   defined on 'Grid_Goster'.  Remove one
>   definition.
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Both
> ```
>
> DataSource and DataSourceID are
>   defined on 'Grid_Goster'.  Remove one
>   definition.

**Source Error:**

> ```
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> ```
>
> current web request. Information
>   regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using

And in my .cs file there is code like this.

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            Grid_Goster.DataSource = dr;
            Grid_Goster.Visible = true;
```

i think this code works correctly.
How can i solve this `DataSource` and `DataSourceID` problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is a dumb question; but it's good to ask just for clarification. Are you specifying both a datasource object (in your code behind) **AND** DatasourceID (in your ASPX markup) on the same control? I'd imagine that it wouldn't work when you try to Databind due to the Datasource ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

There must be manual binding inside your code behind. Either remove the manual binding or the SQL datasource.